# Confusion with Pem Pass Phrase and Challenge Password

Tags: openssl

When creating a CSR with openSSL it asks me:

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

After that it asks:

```
Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
```

I read that pem pass phrase is for encrypting the key file. And any service(like apache) using the key file will ask for pem pass phrase when rebooting the service. Then what is challenge password?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This adds the `challengePassword` attribute to the certificate request, described in [PKCS#9](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-9-v2/pkcs-9.pdf) section 5.4.1:

> #### 5.4.1 Challenge password
>
> The `challengePassword` attribute type specifies a password by which an entity may
> request certificate revocation. The interpretation of challenge passwords is intended to be
> specified by certificate issuers etc; no particular interpretation is required.

This attribute is part of the request and will not be present in the final certificate. In most  cases, you can just leave this attribute empty – most CAs ignore it.

Comment: To hammer in the point - the use of the challenge password is an obsolete, I know of no CAs that uses it today.